# Where are the CA certs on Solaris 10

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, solaris-10

I want to find and update the ca certs on the machine but I don't know their location.

They are not located under `/etc/pki/tls/certs/` like for Linux machines

Comment: My Solaris knowledge is a bit rusty compared to my Linux skills but isn't the default location for CA certificates (if any) not very much dependant on the application's SSL/TLS implementation or the crypto library used? For instance wouldn't a Java application refer to a keystore rather than a directory with CA-certs in PEM format?

Comment: _Some_ Linux distros use /etc/pki/tls, others use something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the  [cacertificate package](https://www.opencsw.org/package/cacertificates/) is installed, the ca certificates will be under `/etc/opt/csw/ssl/certs`

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer for Solaris 11 (even though tags specify 10, this was the first hit when I needed the same info, but for Solaris 11):

```
/etc/certs/CA/
```

in PEM format, vendor provided. Not sure about back-porting from 11 to 10.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54783/kmf-cacerts.html